# Swing: JOptionPane doesn't have X (close) button in top right corner

Tags: java, swing

So my job uses a legacy Swing application, and I just found the weirdest (admittedly tiny) bug in the world, and I have no idea what the cause of this could be.

In this one piece of the UI, any JOptionPane generated doesn't have the X button in the top right corner. Everywhere else in the application it's fine, but just there in that panel it doesn't.

I haven't even the slightest idea where to begin on this one. I didn't even know it was possible to remove that from a JOptionPane.

If anyone could even begin to point me in the direction of what to look for, that would be great. Thanks.

Edit: Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myl0L.png

[image]

Edit: This is the exact code that calls the dialog:

```
String name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(fmContext.getView(), "Enter a name: ",
                        "Add New", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, name);
```

Comment: Can you provide an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And an image of how it looks?

Comment: Maybe you are creating a `new JOptionPane(...)` instead of `JOptionPane.showXxxDialog` ?

Comment: What's your OS and JRE version?

Comment: Added a screenshot. It's not <code>new JOptionPane(..)</code>, it's <code>JOptionPane.showXxxDialog</code>. OSX (newest one), and JRE 7.

Comment: Again, for better help sooner please post a Runnable Example also called [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) This will attract more, faster and better responses

Comment: Have you tried with a simple example? Outside from your program? What happens? Is it showing the `X` button? If so, then it's most probably a code setting on your program, if it isn't it most likely is a misconfiguration on your OS and Java

Comment: I've deleted my answer, the code shows it is not an embeded JOptionPane in a undecorated dialog.

Comment: What is the Look and Feel that you have used here?